# Master-Detail View, Getting a "back" call in the detail view

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

What I have is a Master view that is embedded in a nav controller and when you push a button it navigates to a different master view and causes a replace segue for the detail view.

What I would like is when the automatic "back button" is pressed, the detail view goes back to the "title" version which I'm using as a splash screen.

**Things I've tried so far**

- Delegating UINavigationBar
- Manually forcing a segue when the Master view associated with it's "linked" detailview goes off screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

Need to get the "splash page" to call the segue. I did do this, BUT I did it with "replace" type, which doesn't allow for "pop" transitions